# Confused as to how I set my state incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was showing my friend a program I created a couple weeks ago and when I showed him the code, he mentioned to me that I had "set my state incorrectly". My code worked fine so I asked him to clarify what this meant. He said that the way I set my state was unconventional and was not the correct way of setting it. I didn't think much of it at the time, but recently I've been wanting to improve my React skills so it has caused a bit of concern for me.

I'm wondering if someone can help clarify how I "set my state unconventionally" or a way I'm not supposed to.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import Counter from "./Counter"

class Flipper extends Component {
    state = {
        headsCount: 0,
        tailsCount: 0,
        imgSrc: ""
    }

    addCounter = () => {
        var coinSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        if (coinSide === 0){
            var newHCount = this.state.headsCount + 1
            this.setState({headsCount: newHCount, imgSrc: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/S_Half_Dollar_Obverse_2016.jpg"})
        }else{
            var newTCount = this.state.tailsCount + 1
            this.setState({tailsCount: newTCount, imgSrc: "http://www.pcgscoinfacts.com/UserImages/71009269r.jpg"})
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Let's flip a coin</h1>
                <img src = {this.state.imgSrc}></img>
                <button onClick = {this.addCounter}>Flip Me!</button>
                <Counter headsCount = {this.state.headsCount} tailsCount = {this.state.tailsCount}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Flipper
```

Comment: I don't see any serious issues here.

Comment: That's because the "cool kids" are using useState nowadays

Comment: I suggest you go back to your friend and ask for more details. However, one thing that I'd improve in your code is to use the `callback` function of `setState` to update your `state` based on a previous value - `this.setState(state => ({ headsCount: state.headsCount + newHCount }))` - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a huge problem per se but if you do wish to improve, the conventional way to go about updating state that is somehow related to the previous state is a little different.

The thing is, state updates may be asynchronous and react sometimes batches multiple setState() calls into a single state update. This is why you can't rely on the previous value of your state without explicitly passing the older state.

For example, you're incrementing the count of heads and tails by depending on the 'current' value of state. A fullproof way to go about something like this :-

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
    headsCount : state.headsCount + 1,
    imgsrc :...
});
```

If you set your state like this, you can rest assured that no matter how React batches its setState calls, your state value will never be stale.

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer man! I appreciate it a lot :D